# SMTP configuration from C# to web.config XML translation

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, smtp

I try to move the SMTP setting from C# to XML. I stumbled in setting the network credential, see last line. What is the right syntax in XML for it?

```
using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
{
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    smtp.Port = 587;
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(md.From, "password");
    await smtp.SendMailAsync(msg);
}
```

The SMTP old version setting in the `web.config` file:

```
<mailSettings>
    <smtp from="From@gmail.com">
        <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="From@gmail.com"
                 password="*******" enableSsl="true" />
    </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Comment: how does your xml look like currently/

Comment: I  edited my post  and add the old XML code in the web.config